# Function with write statement hangs up

Tags: fortran

Consider the following code:

```
program test

   real :: out

   out = f(1)

   write(*,*) out

   write(*,*) f(1)

contains

   function f(i)
      integer, intent(in) :: i
      !> Result
      real :: f

      write(*,*) 'in f', i

      f = i*2.0
   end function f

end program test
```

The write statement inside the `f` function is supposed to be for debugging purposes only. The first call to `f` executes correctly, whereas the second call through the `write` statement results in the program hanging up. The output is:

```
 in f           1
   2.0000000000000000
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?

I tested the code on macOS (M1 Max Macbook) using gfortran compiler:

```sh
gfortran-mp-11 -fimplicit-none -fdefault-real-8 test.f90 -o test.exe; ./test.exe
```

Same results using either gcc11 (MacPorts gcc11 11.2.0_1) or gcc-devel (MacPorts gcc-devel 12-20220101_2+enable_stdlib_flag).

Comment: @veryreverie, the code has something wrong: the output statement in the function is a non-child recursive output statement to the same unit.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33804674/3157076).