# Can I put a WRITE statement in a FUNCTION?

Tags: function, fortran

Doing some retrocomputing here.

The question is simple: can I put a WRITE statement in a FUNCTION?  It seems not, cfr., the follwing code snippet

```
      INTEGER FUNCTION CURSED()
      I = 42
      WRITE(6, 2023) I
 2023 FORMAT('>>> In CURSED = ', I4)
      CURSED = I
      RETURN
      END
```

If I call this function the program hangs.  If I comment out the WRITE and FORMAT everything seems fine.

chatGPT says it's in the standard, but the reference it gives are bogus. :)

Any proper explanation?

I tried it with gfortran on MacOS and Windows.

Comment: Yes you can, but if you do then that function can't be [used in certain ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24924196/3157076). Please provide a [mre] so we can tell you whether the way you try to use the function is one of the bad ways.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/axMsGfPra), please post a [mre].

Comment: Agree with @francescalus.  The rules get a bit messy and depend of the Fortran standard version that you're following.  But a not-bad general rule is to avoid recursive IO.  IOW, do not do `write(*,*) cursed()`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, note the sensitivity to OS in [this other case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33804674/3157076), once recursive I/O is introduced.

Comment: Hi... thank you all.  As @steve pointed out.  The problem was this notion of "recursive" IO.

I was, in fact, trying to do something like

`WRITE(6, 666) CURSED()`

in the main program.  I now understand this is a no-no.  But where in the Fortran 77 (yes! 77) standard is this spelled out?

Comment: See F77 section 12.11.  _A function must not be referenced within an expression appearing anywhere in an input/output statement if such a reference causes an input/output statement to be executed._

Comment: Thank you @steve.  You just corrected chatGPT :) :) :)

Comment: Thanks @francescalus yeas, I did see that message as well.
Happy Holydays.